# Collecting data to a google sheet from a webapp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, jsignature

I have a basic sheet with the jSignature code that works and collects the data from the webapp when published.  I wanted to add on this so had created another sheet and followed the same layout.  Admittedly, I am just a copy and paste coder at this time.  I understand a lot of what I'm reading, but some things just don't register to me yet.  I can't for the life of me figure out why the first sheet works and the second doesn't.  *the working sheet only works with the folder id put in, I believe, so you'll have to replace that.

Here is the link to the sheet that works (hopefully all can view):  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uJk7ZkOKUp1Z8afTxVZ1uRdoTCxa08MRYQtVcOmTOAk

and the one that doesn't:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tINd-54djeIhfOL3laLNXiohNlAPONb6MDA6Y_xQUKI

If for whatever reason those links don't work, here are the code snippets:

Working Code.gs

```
function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('jSignature')
    .setWidth(400)
    .setHeight(300);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .showModalDialog(html, 'Your Signature is Required');
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('jSignature')
      .evaluate();
}

function saveImage(bytes, sign){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Register');
  var dateObj = Date.now();
  var bytes = bytes.split(",")
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(bytes[1]), 'image/png');
  var fileName = blob.setName("Signature "+dateObj).getName();
  var sigFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("myfolderid"); //replace with your folder id
  var url = sigFolder.createFile(blob).getId();
  Logger.log(url)
  var name = sign.username;
  var employeenumber = sign.useremployeenumber;
  var signature = ss.insertImage(blob,4,ss.getLastRow()+1);
  signature.setWidth(500);
  signature.setHeight(20);
  signature
  var imageCell = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 3).setValues([[Date(), name,employeenumber]]);
}
```

Working .html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/></head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/willowsystems/jSignature/master/libs/jSignature.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form id="customerForm">
Please sign your name in the pad below: <br>
Full Name: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Employee Number: <input type="employeenumber" name="useremployeenumber"><br><br>
Signature:
<div id="signature"></div><br>
<img id="rendered" src="" style="display:none">
<input type="Submit" value="Save" onclick="renderSignature();saveImage();"/>
</form>
</body>
<script>
  document.getElementById("signature").style.border = "1px solid black";

  $("#signature").jSignature({
    'background-color': 'transparent',
    'decor-color': 'transparent'
  });

  function renderSignature(){
    $("img#rendered").attr("src",$('#signature').jSignature('getData','default'));
  }

  function saveImage(e){ //This sends the image src to saveImages function
    var bytes = document.getElementById('rendered').src;
    console.log(bytes);
    var sign = {
      username: document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value,
      useremployeenumber: document.getElementsByName('useremployeenumber')[0].value
    };
    google.script.run.saveImage(bytes, sign);
    return
  } 
  window.onload=function(){
  google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close();})
.saveImage(bytes, sign);
}

</script>
</html>
```

non-working code.gs

```
function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('jSignature')
    .setWidth(400)
    .setHeight(300);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .showModalDialog(html, 'Your Signature is Required');
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('jSignature')
      .evaluate();
}

function saveImage(bytes, sign){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('FormResponse');
  var dateObj = Date.now();
  var bytes = bytes.split(",")
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(bytes[1]), 'image/png');
  var fileName = blob.setName("Signature "+dateObj).getName();
  var sigFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("myfolderid"); //replace with your folder id
  var url = sigFolder.createFile(blob).getId();
  Logger.log(url)
  var carrier = sign.carrier;
  var address = sign.address;
  var dname = sign.dname;
  var dnum = sign.dnum;
  var date = sign.date;
  var time = sign.time;
  var tractortruck = sign.tractortruck;
  var odom = sign.odom;
  var aircompressor = sign.aircompressor;
  var airlines = sign.airlines;
  var BeltsandHoses = sign.BeltsandHoses;
  var Body = sign.Body;
  var BrakeAccessories = sign.BrakeAccessories;
  var BrakesParking = sign.BrakesParking;
  var BrakesService = sign.BrakesService;
  var Clutch = sign.Clutch;
  var CouplingDevices = sign.CouplingDevices;
  var DefrosterHeater = sign.DefrosterHeater;
  var DriveLine = sign.DriveLine;
  var Engine = sign.Engine;
  var Exhaust = sign.Exhaust;
  var FifthWheel = sign.FifthWheel;
  var FluidLevels = sign.FluidLevels;
  var FrameandAssembly = sign.FrameandAssembly;
  var FrontAxle = sign.FrontAxle;
  var FuelTanks = sign.FuelTanks;
  var Horn = sign.Horn;
  var Lights = sign.Lights;
  var Mirrors = sign.Mirrors;
  var Muffler = sign.Muffler;
  var OilPressure = sign.OilPressure;
  var Radiator = sign.Radiator;
  var RearEnd = sign.RearEnd;
  var Reflectors = sign.Reflectors;
  var SafetyEquipment = sign.SafetyEquipment;
  var Starter = sign.Starter;
  var Steering = sign.Steering;
  var SuspensionSystem = sign.SuspensionSystem;
  var TireChains = sign.TireChains;
  var Tires = sign.Tires;
  var Transmission = sign.Transmission;
  var TripRecorder = sign.TripRecorder;
  var WheelsandRims = sign.WheelsandRims;
  var Windows = sign.Windows;
  var WindshieldWipers = sign.WindshieldWipers;
  var Other = sign.Other;
  var signature = ss.insertImage(blob,47,ss.getLastRow()+1);
  signature.setWidth(500);
  signature.setHeight(20);
  signature
  var imageCell = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 46).setValues([[carrier, address, dname, dnum, date, time, tractortruck, odom, aircompressor, airlines, BeltsandHoses, Body, BrakeAccessories, BrakesParking, BrakesService, Clutch, CouplingDevices, DefrosterHeater, DriveLine, Engine, Exhaust, FifthWheel, FluidLevels, FrameandAssembly, FrontAxle, FuelTanks, Horn, Lights, Mirrors, Muffler, OilPressure, Radiator, RearEnd, Reflectors, SafetyEquipment, Starter, Steering, SuspensionSystem, TireChains, Tires, Transmission, TripRecorder, WheelsandRims, Windows, WindshieldWipers, Other]]);
}
```

non-working html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/></head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/willowsystems/jSignature/master/libs/jSignature.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

input[type=text], select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 2em;
}
input[type=number], select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 2em;
}
input[type=date], select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 2em;
}

input[type=time], select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 2em;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1em;
}
input[type=radio] {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

#signature {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  }
#Inspection th, #Inspection td {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
#Inspection td {
  width: 60%;
  }
#Inspection th {
  width: 20%;
  }
#customerForm {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: Bold;
  }
  ::placeholder {
  font-size: 1em;
  }

</style>
<body>
<center><h1><big><big>DRIVER VEHICLE INSPECTION REPORT</big></big></h1>
<h5>AS REQUIRED BY THE D.O.T. FEDERAL MOTOR CARRIER SAFETY REGULATIONS</h5></center><br>
<form id="customerForm">
<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="carrier">Carrier:</label>
    <select id="carrier" name="carrier" required>
      <option value="My Company">My Company</option>   
      </select><br>
      <label for="address">Address:</label>
    <select id="address" name="address" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select your location</option>
      <option value="PDX">PDX</option>
      <option value="SEA">SEA</option>
      <option value="SFO">SFO</option>
      </select><br>
      <label for="Driver name">Driver Performing Inspection:</label>
  <input type="text" id="dname" name="drivername" placeholder="Your full name" required><br>
  <label for="Driver Employee ID number">Driver's Employee Number:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="dnum" name="drivernumber" placeholder="Your employee number" required><br><br>
  <label for="Date">Date Performed:</label><br>
  <input type="date" id="date" name="date" required><br><br>
  <label for="Time">Time Performed:</label><br>
  <input type="time" id="time" name="time" value="now" required><br><br>
  <label for="Tractor/Truck#">Tractor / Truck #:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="tractor/truck" name="tractor/truck" placeholder="Your vehicle number" required><br><br>
  <label for="Odometer">Odometer Reading:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="odom" name="odometer reading" placeholder="Vehicle odometer reading" required><br><br>
  <center><h3>Tractor / Truck Inspection:</h3><br></center>
  <table id= "Inspection">
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <th>Satisfactory</th>
  <th>Unsatisfactory</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Air Compressor">Air Compressor</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="air compressor" name="air compressor" value="Sat" required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="air compressor" name="air compressor" value="Unsat" required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Air Lines">Air Lines</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="air lines" name="air lines" value="Sat" required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="air lines" name="air lines" value="Unsat" required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Battery">Battery</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Battery" name="Battery" value="Sat" required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Battery" name="Battery" value="Unsat" required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Belts and Hoses">Belts and Hoses</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Belts and Hoses" name="Belts and Hoses" value="Sat" required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Belts and Hoses" name="Belts and Hoses" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Body">Body</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Body" name="Body" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Body" name="Body" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Brake Accessories">Brake Accessories</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Brake Accessories" name="Brake Accessories" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Brake Accessories" name="Brake Accessories" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Brakes, Parking">Brakes, Parking</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Brakes, Parking" name="Brakes, Parking" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Brakes, Parking" name="Brakes, Parking" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Brakes, Service">Brakes, Service</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Brakes, Service" name="Brakes, Service" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Brakes, Service" name="Brakes, Service" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Clutch">Clutch</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Clutch" name="Clutch" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Clutch" name="Clutch" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Coupling Devices">Coupling Devices</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Coupling Devices" name="Coupling Devices" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Coupling Devices" name="Coupling Devices" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Defroster/Heater">Defroster/Heater</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Defroster/Heater" name="Defroster/Heater" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Defroster/Heater" name="Defroster/Heater" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Drive Line">Drive Line</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Drive Line" name="Drive Line" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Drive Line" name="Drive Line" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Engine">Engine</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Engine" name="Engine" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Engine" name="Engine" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Exhaust">Exhaust</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Exhaust" name="Exhaust" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Exhaust" name="Exhaust" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Fifth Wheel">Fifth Wheel</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Fifth Wheel" name="Fifth Wheel" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Fifth Wheel" name="Fifth Wheel" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Fluid Levels">Fluid Levels</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Fluid Levels" name="Fluid Levels" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Fluid Levels" name="Fluid Levels" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Frame and Assembly">Frame and Assembly</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Frame and Assembly" name="Frame and Assembly" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Frame and Assembly" name="Frame and Assembly" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Front Axle">Front Axle</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Front Axle" name="Front Axle" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Front Axle" name="Front Axle" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Fuel Tanks">Fuel Tanks</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Fuel Tanks" name="Fuel Tanks" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Fuel Tanks" name="Fuel Tanks" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Horn">Horn</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Horn" name="Horn" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Horn" name="Horn" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Lights">Lights -<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Head/Stop<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tail/Dash<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Turn Indicators<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Clearance/Marker</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Lights" name="Lights" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Lights" name="Lights" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Mirrors">Mirrors</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Mirrors" name="Mirrors" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Mirrors" name="Mirrors" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Muffler">Muffler</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Muffler" name="Muffler" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Muffler" name="Muffler" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Oil Pressure">Oil Pressure</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Oil Pressure" name="Oil Pressure" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Oil Pressure" name="Oil Pressure" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Radiator">Radiator</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Radiator" name="Radiator" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Radiator" name="Radiator" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Rear End">Rear End</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Rear End" name="Rear End" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Rear End" name="Rear End" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Reflectors">Reflectors</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Reflectors" name="Reflectors" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Reflectors" name="Reflectors" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Safety Equipment">Safety Equipment -<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fire Extinguisher<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Flags/Flares/Fusees<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reflective Triangles<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Spare Bulbs and Fuses<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Spare Seal Beam</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Safety Equipment" name="Safety Equipment" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Safety Equipment" name="Safety Equipment" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Starter">Starter</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" name="Starter" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" name="Starter" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Steering">Steering</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Steering" name="Steering" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Steering" name="Steering" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Suspension System">Suspension System</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Suspension System" name="Suspension System" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Suspension System" name="Suspension System" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Tire Chains">Tire Chains</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Tire Chains" name="Tire Chains" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Tire Chains" name="Tire Chains" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Tires">Tires</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Tires" name="Tires" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Tires" name="Tires" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Transmission">Transmission</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Transmission" name="Transmission" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Transmission" name="Transmission" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Trip Recorder">Trip Recorder</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Trip Recorder" name="Trip Recorder" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Trip Recorder" name="Trip Recorder" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Wheels and Rims">Wheels and Rims</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Wheels and Rims" name="Wheels and Rims" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Wheels and Rims" name="Wheels and Rims" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Windows">Windows</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Windows" name="Windows" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Windows" name="Windows" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Windshield Wipers">Windshield Wipers</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Windshield Wipers" name="Windshield Wipers" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Windshield Wipers" name="Windshield Wipers" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="Other">Other</label></td>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Other" name="Other" value="Sat"required></th>
  <th><input type="radio" id="Other" name="Other" value="Unsat"required></th>
  </tr>
  </table><br>
<b><big>Signature:</big></b>
<div id="signature"></div><br>
<img id="rendered" src="" style="display:none">
<input type="submit" value="Submit and close" onclick="renderSignature();saveImage();"/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
<script>

  $("#signature").jSignature({
    'background-color': 'transparent',
    'decor-color': 'transparent',
  });

  function renderSignature(){
    $("img#rendered").attr("src",$('#signature').jSignature('getData','default'));
  }

  function saveImage(e){ //This sends the image src to saveImages function
    var bytes = document.getElementById('rendered').src;
    console.log(bytes);
    var sign = {
      carrier: document.getElementsByName('carrier')[0].value,
      address: document.getElementsByName('address')[0].value,
      dname: document.getElementsByName('dname')[0].value,
      dnum: document.getElementsByName('dnum')[0].value,
      date: document.getElementsByName('date')[0].value,
      time: document.getElementsByName('time')[0].value,
      tractortruck: document.getElementsByName('tractor/truck')[0].value,
      odom: document.getElementsByName('odom')[0].value,
      aircompressor: document.getElementsByName('air compressor')[0].value,
      airlines: document.getElementsByName('air lines')[0].value,
      BeltsandHoses: document.getElementsByName('Belts and Hoses')[0].value,
      Body: document.getElementsByName('Body')[0].value,
      BrakeAccessories: document.getElementsByName('Brake Accessories')[0].value,
      BeltsandHoses: document.getElementsByName('Belts and Hoses')[0].value,
      BrakesParking: document.getElementsByName('Brakes, Parking')[0].value,
      BrakesService: document.getElementsByName('Brakes, Service')[0].value,
      Clutch: document.getElementsByName('Clutch')[0].value,
      CouplingDevices: document.getElementsByName('Coupling Devices')[0].value,
      DefrosterHeater: document.getElementsByName('Defroster/Heater')[0].value,
      DriveLine: document.getElementsByName('Drive Line')[0].value,
      Engine: document.getElementsByName('Engine')[0].value,
      Exhaust: document.getElementsByName('Exhaust')[0].value,
      FifthWheel: document.getElementsByName('Fifth Wheel')[0].value,
      FluidLevels: document.getElementsByName('Fluid Levels')[0].value,
      FrameandAssembly: document.getElementsByName('Frame and Assembly')[0].value,
      FrontAxle: document.getElementsByName('Front Axle')[0].value,
      FuelTanks: document.getElementsByName('Fuel Tanks')[0].value,
      Horn: document.getElementsByName('Horn')[0].value,
      Lights: document.getElementsByName('Lights')[0].value,
      Mirrors: document.getElementsByName('Mirrors')[0].value,
      Muffler: document.getElementsByName('Muffler')[0].value,
      OilPressure: document.getElementsByName('Oil Pressure')[0].value,
      Radiator: document.getElementsByName('Radiator')[0].value,
      RearEnd: document.getElementsByName('Rear End')[0].value,
      Reflectors: document.getElementsByName('Reflectors')[0].value,
      SafetyEquipment: document.getElementsByName('Safety Equipment')[0].value,
      Starter: document.getElementsByName('Starter')[0].value,
      Steering: document.getElementsByName('Steering')[0].value,
      SuspensionSystem: document.getElementsByName('Suspension System')[0].value,
      TireChains: document.getElementsByName('Tire Chains')[0].value,
      Tires: document.getElementsByName('Tires')[0].value,
      Transmission: document.getElementsByName('Transmission')[0].value,
      TripRecorder: document.getElementsByName('Trip Recorder')[0].value,
      WheelsandRims: document.getElementsByName('Wheels and Rims')[0].value,
      Windows: document.getElementsByName('Windows')[0].value,
      WindshieldWipers: document.getElementsByName('Windshield Wipers')[0].value,
      Other: document.getElementsByName('Other')[0].value
    };
    google.script.run.saveImage(bytes, sign);
    return
  }
  window.onload=function(){
  google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close();})
.saveImage(bytes, sign);
}
let date = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10);
document.querySelector("#date").value = date;

$(function(){     
  var d = new Date(),        
      h = d.getHours(),
      m = d.getMinutes();
  if(h < 10) h = '0' + h; 
  if(m < 10) m = '0' + m; 
  $('input[type="time"][value="now"]').each(function(){ 
    $(this).attr({'value': h + ':' + m});
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

I am looking to publish this as a webapp and be able to collect the responses in the sheet.

Thank you.

Comment: You should make those sheets publicly available after scrubbing them for sensitive info if you haven't done that already.

Comment: The person in charge of my domain has the settings set to prevent public sharing.  I have given you access to the pages though.

Comment: Right now, my best guess is that is has to do with getting the value from multiple radio buttons.  Apparently, the way I have it wrote currently is not correct and two radios can't share an ID.  I am doing some research on this and should have a change soon.  I don't think that's my only problem, but it's something to go off of now.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Which error messages do you get? It is helpful to implement `console.log` into your code which allows you too see the logs in the browser when deploying the webapp.  If you replace the non-working code in the non-working sheet through the working code - will the non-working sheet then work?

Comment: Given that it is deployed as a webapp, I don't see any errors.  It just doesn't transfer to my google sheet like the working code does.  It is my best guess right now that it has something to do with the radio buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There are two issues with your script:

1. you call

```
      ...
      dname: document.getElementsByName('dname')[0].value,
      dnum: document.getElementsByName('dnum')[0].value,
      ...
```

instead of

```
       ...
      dname: document.getElementsByName('drivername')[0].value,
      dnum: document.getElementsByName('drivernumber')[0].value,
      ...
```

but there are no elements with the names 'dname' and 'dnum' (don't mix up names with Ids...)

There are several wrong getElementsByName() calls - change them all.

2. You call

```
    google.script.run.saveImage(bytes, sign);
```

both within `function saveImage(e)` and `window.onload=function()`

Remove the second one - you don't need to call `saveImage(bytes, sign)` twice, and also within `window.onload=function()` `bytes` and `sign` are not defined.

Those are the error messages in the console that helped me to identify the errors:

[image]

[image]

[Console logs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_log.asp) are also very helpful for troubleshooting.

Comment: Wow, that totally worked perfect!  The only thing that I can't quite get is the collection of the selected radio button.  No matter what value is selected, I receive only the first value.  In this case, I only receive "Sat" back from every radio input.  Do you know how to correct that?

Comment: @NMALM: You have several buttons with the same name, but you always retrieve the first one with `getElementsByName('XXX')[0]`. Instead you need to retrieve the checked button (which might be `getElementsByName('XXX')[1]`). You can do so by retrieving the `checked` status with a for loop and if statement, see sample: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-value-of-selected-radio-button-using-javascript/